# Grid layout using grid-column and grid-row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using the grid rows and column. I am getting the issue at the last element. I need the second row with equal height and width. So I tried below code.

expected output is
[image]

I am getting the output
[image]

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.content div {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 1/3
}

.two {
  grid-column: 4/6;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3/5
}

.four {
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 5/6;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
  <div class="five">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the number `5` which make it difficult to divide by `3`. Use `15` for example and you can easily divide it by `3` and for the first row you will have `9 + 6` instead of `3 + 2`

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.content div {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1/10;
  grid-row: 1/3
}

.two {
  grid-column: 10/16;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1/6;
  grid-row: 3/5
}

.four {
  grid-column: 6/11;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 11/16;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
  <div class="five">5</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As per the OP comments, this is the correct output needed:

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.content div {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/3
}

.two {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/5
}

.four {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
  <div class="five">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to understand, Why you used 15?

Comment: Is it the second(2) div is the same width and hight of the 3,4,5? I need equal. Please assist me

Comment: @user9437856 I used a numbe that I can divide by 3 ... 5 will not allow to divide by 3 for the last row. I don't understand that last part, can you clear it ?

Comment: What I am doing is I need 2,3,4,5 with equal and 1 one need big like expect output.

Comment: Yes your jsfiddle is absolutely correct. I need like this only. Can you assist me how you solved this?

Comment: @user9437856 it's easy: As you can see I put the columns number to be 3 `repeat(3, 1fr)` and all the elements will take `1fr` so they will have `grid-column:n/n+1` BUT the first one will be bigger and will take `2fr` and will have `grid-column:n/n+2`

Comment: Give me some time to understand your answer